# COUNTIF Unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, countif

I used this formula to find SKU counts in certain categories given multiple criteria:

```
=+COUNTIFS(Data!$AG:$AG, ">"&0,Data!$AO:$AO, "="&$A115,Data!$L:$L, "="&D$104,Data!$P:$P,$B$103)
```

I am able to find the SKU counts but it gives me the total SKU count, I believe because it now counts any SKU with inventory greater than 0 with my multiple criteria.

How can I change the formula to get the unique SKU count per division?

```
Column AG: Inventory
Column AO: Division Name
Column  L: Month
Column  P: Year
Column  T: SKU Code(written out) - what I need to find unique values of.
```

Example here:  [dropbox.com/s/hxbt7hb9l8hf4w6/Sample%20Example.xlsx?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxbt7hb9l8hf4w6/Sample%20Example.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532773/how-to-count-unique-values-in-excel-with-two-conditions

Comment: @JohnBustos I couldn't seem to get it from that post....

Comment: @jbarker2160-cant send more of sample as it's confidential data.

Comment: But can't you at least create a small sample of mocked-up dummy data which at least illustrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: @XORLX i am new to the site and I canned find out how to attach the sample file on to the message board. any suggestions?

Comment: @pnuts here is the sample file    https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxbt7hb9l8hf4w6/Sample%20Example.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @pnuts I'd rather not use distinct count as using power pivot makes  the application unstable. Any solutions using regular excel functions or do I need to use power pivot?

Comment: @pnuts I did not use a pivot, I am assuming OP means original Pivot. What does OP mean?  I just used excel functions to get the table from the data.

Comment: Can you add helper columns to your input sheet?

Comment: @Captain what do you mean by helper columns?

Comment: @Bryan - could you add a column on your input sheet with an intermediary formula... or is you input sheet something that you cannot touch? If the input sheet had a column with formula of `=1/COUNTIFS(...your categorization...)` you can then `SUMIFS` on summary sheet to get the equivalent to the distinct count

Comment: @Captain In a perfect world id like the input sheet to stay the same, but if I needed a helper column to get the job done, I am open to it.  Could you give me a little more detail on how I would do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Captain Thanks for the help! I made the countifs helper column and then put the following formula on the calculation sheet, but to no avail...I think I am almost there.  Any thoughts=+SUMIFS(Data!$BG:$BG,Data!$AO:$AO,"="&$A105,Data!$L:$L,"="&B$104,Data!$P:$P,$B$103)

Answer (score 0):

If you created a helper column on the input sheet with the formula (e.g. in `BG2`):

```
=1/COUNTIFS(T:T,T2,AG:AG,">0",AO:AO,AO2,L:L,L2,P:P,P2)
```

This means that if you had, for example, 5 times the SKU in one Division/Month/Year, you would get 1/5. Then, in the calculation sheet, replace your `COUNTIFS` with a `SUMIFS` (summing your new helper column, using same conditions). This will mean that your 5 duplicates (with `1/5` in the helper) get summed to `1` - i.e. 1 unique SKU

**EDIT**

Because there are some where there is no positive inventory, the count gives you 0 and you get a `#DIV/0!` error... so we can fix that with:

```
=IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS(T:T,T2,AG:AG,">0",AO:AO,AO2,L:L,L2,P:P,P2),0)
```

Then, in the Output-EOM Unique SKU Count sheet, in cell e.g. B6, use:

```
=SUMIFS(input!$BG:$BG,input!$AO:$AO,$A6,input!$L:$L,B$5,input!$P:$P,$B$4)
```

Comment: @bryan Did this work for you? Feel free to accept the answer!