# How to count unique values from different named Excel table with conditions using array formula?

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have two tables (One that is used to capture every record, the other for capturing a summary of the records).

**Tracker Table** - Columns: Code, Date, Error Message

**Summary Table** - Columns: Code, Errors Count, Unique Errors

Currently, I use the following to retrieve the number of errors total from each app code in the Errors Count column:
`{=COUNT(IF([@Code]=Tracker[Code],1))}`

i.e. If I have the following in the **Tracker Table**:

`1234 | Dec 01 34 | Error 1111 has occurred in Application 1234`

`1234 | Dec 23 34 | Error 1111 has occurred in Application 1234`

`1234 | Dec 23 34 | Error 4444 has occurred in Application 1234`

Then in the **Summary Table** I should have:

`1234 | 3 | 2`

I had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532773/how-to-count-unique-values-in-excel-with-two-conditions) (below formula), I can target the column in named table for the ranges (`B2:B100`, `A2:A100`), but I don't know what to use for the `ROW(A2)` target.

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B100=1,IF(A2:A100<>"",MATCH(A2:A100,A2:A100,0))),ROW(A2:A100)-ROW(A2)+1),1))`

What array formula do I use to find the unique number of each error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(([@Code]=Tracker[Code])/COUNTIFS(Tracker[Error Message],Tracker[Error Message],Tracker[Code],[@Code]),0))
```

The basic approach is to divide 1 buy the number of times a certain `Error Message` appears and then `SUM` those... This will give you the unique number of messages.

We add in the initial `[@Code]=Tracker[Code]` so that we get a `1` or `0` to for the numerator (i.e. ignore those rows that don't match the `Code`) as well as the extra `COUNTIFS` condition `...,Tracker[Code],[@Code]` so that we only count the occurrences of the `Error Message` with the matching `Code`

The `IFERROR` is to get rid of those pesky `#DIV/0!` errors for the unmatched rows...