# Count unique alphanumeric value with two criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

this question may be repeated from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532773/how-to-count-unique-values-in-excel-with-two-conditions)
but the vales in my situation are alpha numeric.
I would like to find number of unique materials that I received in specific calendar week with specific type.

Attached is the image. Kindly provide your suggestion.Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly then following formula should work for you:

```
=SUM(IF(((MATCH($A$2:$A$8&$B$2:$B$8&$C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8&$B$2:$B$8&$C$2:$C$8,0))>=(ROW($A$2:$A$8)-(MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$8))-1)))*(($C$2:$C$8=$E2)*(($A$2:$A$8)=F$1))=1,1,0))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down and across as required.

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: I used the above mention formula, it gives me a error #VALUE. Due to "," used instead of ";". I changed it to ";" still i get an error #VALUE. I am using excel 2013.

Comment: @SriLaks - This is an **Array formula** so instead of just pressing `Enter`, you have to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to complete the formula. After formula is successfully entered you should be able to see curly brackets `{ }` around your formula.