# How to count unique values only if two other columns match to specific values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to count the distinct ID values whenever location and date equal specific values.

There are a handful of articles/questions out there that outline a few different ways to do this (e.g. [How to count unique values in Excel with two conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532773/how-to-count-unique-values-in-excel-with-two-conditions)), but for some reason none seem to be working for me (which is likely because I'm doing something wrong).

My table in excel is set up like so

```
+------------------+--------------+------------+
| Col A - Location | Col B - Date | Col C - ID |
+------------------+--------------+------------+
|         A        |   Mar 2018   |      1     |         
|         B        |   Mar 2018   |      2     |
|         C        |   Mar 2018   |      3     |
|         A        |   Mar 2018   |      4     |
|         B        |   Mar 2018   |            |
|         C        |   Mar 2018   |      5     |
|         A        |   Mar 2018   |      6     |
|         B        |   Apr 2018   |      1     |
|         C        |   Apr 2018   |      2     |
|         C        |   Apr 2018   |      4     |
|         C        |   Mar 2018   |      5     |
|         A        |   Mar 2018   |      1     |
|         B        |   Mar 2018   |      5     |
|         B        |   Mar 2018   |      8     |
|         B        |   Mar 2018   |            |
|         C        |   Mar 2018   |      1     |
|         B        |   Mar 2018   |      3     |
+------------------+--------------+------------+
```

I tried 4 different calculations I found online and altered to fit my data:

```
Calc 1 (run by just hitting ENTER):
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "A",C:C,C:C,B:B, "Mar 2018")

Result = 2


Calc 2 (running by hitting CTRL + SHFT + ENTER):
=SUMPRODUCT( ( (C:C <> "") * (A:A = "A") * (B:B = "Mar 2018") ) / COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C  & "",A:A, "A",B:B, "Mar 2018"))

Result = 0


Calc 3 (running by hitting CTRL + SHFT + ENTER):
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(C:C<>"", MATCH(C:C,C:C,0)),ROW(C:C)-ROW(C2)+1),1))

Result = 0


Calc 4 (running by hitting CTRL + SHFT + ENTER):
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((A:A="A")*(B:B="Mar 2018")*(C:C<>""),MATCH(C:C,C:C,0)),ROW(C:C)-MIN(ROW(C:C))+1),1))

Result = 0 
(This one keeps giving an error message about running out of resources while trying to calculate)
```

The actual results I'm trying to find is that for 'Col A - Location' where the value is 'A' and for 'Col B - Date' where the value is 'Mar 2018' the unique # of 'Col C - ID' should be 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to count with multiple criteria is using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A20="A"),--(B1:B20=DATE(2018,3,1)),--(C1:C20=3))
```

the double negative (--) converts the True/False answers into 1 or 0 for sumproduct to do its job.

I suggest that you limit your ranges (i.e. don't use whole columns like A:A) because it will slow the formula (a lot). Also, it might be easier to use a locked reference cell for your conditions. If you input your conditions in the first row, you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A20=$A$1),--(B2:B20=$B$1),--(C1:C20=$C$1))
```

**Edit**

Following beatrixb's clarification, you would need a helper column to concatenate the three columns. Assurming your data start at A2, you would put this in D2 (if you don't already have a unique identifier for each row):

```
=A2&B2&C2
```

And use this formula in another cell to return the number of unique values based on two conditions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A20=$A$1),--(B2:B20=$B$1),(1/COUNTIF(D2:D20,D2:D20)))
```

Comment: thank you, this gets me closer, but not 100% there. I don't want C1:C20 to be equal to any specific value, what I want is to count the unique ID #s for Col C, so in my example given the condition of Col A = 'A' and Col B = 'Mar 2018', there are 4 rows that hit those conditions containing IDs 1, 4, 6, 1, and then since 1 is duplicated, the unique count of IDs would be 3. Is there a way to do a countif as the last sumproduct variable?