# CountIfs for unique values

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, excel-2010

In my spreadsheet I have the following in cells `A5:C12`:

```
ABC 4   B
ABC 5   B
ABC 5   B
ABC 5   C
CBS 4   B
CBS 5   B
CBS 3   C
NBC 4   B
```

I am trying to see the number of unique occurrence of a “5 B”. Here, there are 3 times a 5 and B appear: in `ABC` twice and in `CBS` once.  Thus I would like 2 returned, since there are 2 companies (`ABC` and `CBS`) that have 5 and B.

I tried `=COUNTIFS(B5:B12,5,C5:C12,"B")`, but this returned “3” and couldn’t distinguish between the two ABCs.

The formula `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((C5:C12="B")/COUNTIFS(A5:A12,A5:A12,C5:C12,"B"),0))` returns “3”, telling us there are 3 unique “B”s.

The formula  `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((B5:B12=5)/COUNTIFS(A5:A12,A5:A12,B5:B12,5),0))` returns “2”, telling us there are 2 unique “5”s.

Is there a way to somehow combine the above two formulas (or any other way) to see the number of unique “5B”s?

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED

```
 =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B5:B12&C5:C12="5b",IF(A5:A12<>"",MATCH(A5:A12,A5:A12,0))),ROW(A5:A12)-ROW(A5)+1),1))
```

entered as an array formula (adapted from [Barry Houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944249/excel-count-unique-values-with-a-condition/15945052#15945052)).