# Counting unique list of items from range based on criteria from other ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file with data in the following format:

text  value1  value2

Given value 1 and value 2 meet some criteria, find all the unique text values.

The exact data looks like this:

```
john 10 20
john 15 35
mark 20 10
mark 25 15
tom  25 40
lee  16 50
```

If val 1 <=25 and value 2 <=35  the number of unique text = 2 (john and mark)
I have to do this using formulas not filters.

I've been trying combinations of frequency, countifs, sumproducts and a whole range of other methods and can't seem to hit what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will do what you are asking:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B7<=25,IF(C2:C7<=35,MATCH(A2:A7,A2:A7,0),""),""),IF(B2:B7<=25,IF(C2:C7<=35,MATCH(A2:A7,A2:A7,0),""),""))>0,1))
```

This is an array formula so confirm it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

I referred to [this webpage](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273).

Also found a shorter one:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B7<=25,IF(C2:C7<=35,COUNTIF(A2:A7,"<"&A2:A7),""),""),COUNTIF(A2:A7,"<"&A2:A7))>0))
```

Found and modified from [hre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944249/count-unique-values-with-a-condition).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *list* the unique values rather than count them, something like this:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$7,MATCH(0,IF((B$2:B$7>25)+(C$2:C$7>35),1,COUNTIF(E$1:E2,A$2:A$7)),0)),"")
```

entered as an array formula starting in E2 ( and assuming that you are using columns A,B and C for your data.

See [this reference](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/) for explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that text, value1, and value2 are in columns A, B, and C respectively ...

In D1, enter the formula `=IF(AND(B1<=25,C1<=35),A1,"")` and copy it down the column

Use the formula `=SUMPRODUCT((D:D<>"")/COUNTIF(D:D,D:D&""))` for your answer