# Intermediate steps in evaluation of Frequency formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This has reference to [SO question][Counting unique list of items from range based on criteria from other ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596956/counting-unique-list-of-items-from-range-based-on-criteria-from-other-ranges/34597961#34597961)
Formula Suggested by Scot Craner is :

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B7<=25,IF(C2:C7<=35,COUNTIF(A2:A7,"<"&A2:A7),""),""),COUNTIF(A2:A7,"<"&A2:A7))>0))
```

I have been able to understand clearly the logic and evaluation of the formula except for this step shown in the attached snapshots.
As per MS Office document:

> FREQUENCY(data_array, bins_array) The FREQUENCY function syntax has
>   the following arguments: Data_array    Required. An array of or
>   reference to a set of values for which you want to count frequencies.
>   If data_array contains no values, FREQUENCY returns an array of zeros.
>   Bins_array    Required. An array of or reference to intervals into
>   which you want to group the values in data_array. If bins_array
>   contains no values, FREQUENCY returns the number of elements in
>   data_array.

It is clear to me as to How {1;1;4;0;"";"") comes in data_array and also how {1;1;4;0;5;3} comes in bins_array.But how it evaluates to {2;0;1;1;0;0;0} is not clear to me.
Would appreciate if someone can lucidly explain it.

[image: evaluation stage a][image: evaluation stage b]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you wants to know how

`FREQUENCY({1;1;4;0;"";""},{1;1;4;0;5;3})` evaluates to `{2;0;1;1;0;0;0}`?

Problem is that the `bins_array` not needs to be sorted to make `FREQUENCY` working. But of course it internally must sort the `bins_array` to get the intervals into which to group the values in `data_array`. Then it groups and counts and then it returns the counted numbers in the same order the bins was given in  `bins_array`.

```
Scores   Bins 
1        1
1        1
4        4
0        0
""       5
""       3

Bins sorted
0 (<=0)
1 (>0, <=1)
1 (>1, <=1) == not possible
3 (>1, <=3)
4 (>3, <=4)
5 (>4, <=5)
(>5)

Bin    Description                                     Result
1      Number of scores (>0, <=1)                      2
1      Number of scores (>1, <=1) == not possible      0
4      Number of scores (>3, <=4)                      1
0      Number of scores (<=0)                          1
5      Number of scores (>4, <=5)                      0
3      Number of scores (>1, <=3)                      0
       Number of scores (>5)                           0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very clear and lucid explanation. Now my concepts in this regard are fully clear.