# Counting unique records with multiple criteria for productivity calculation

Tags: excel, date

I have an excel sheet with productivity for my work force. Along with lots of other information about the job, it contains a `job number`, `date`, and `completed by` fields. Each employee may have 50-60 entries for each day they worked.

**What I would like to be able to do:**
Count how many days each employee has worked by applying a formula that counts a day as work if the employee has any entry against that date (this tracker if for a full year so I'm looking for a way that avoids typing each day of the year).

For example, I want to be able to say to employee A, "You completed 4,000 jobs over 165 days which puts you productivity rate at..."

I want to count the unique values in the date column if `Name` = `Employee A`. My data set is about 20K records covering a full year.

[[image: This is the data i have, with 20k rows][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Izq.png)

[image: This is how i wish to present]

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944249/count-unique-values-with-a-condition) is a good starting point.   Try these suggestions if you get stuck come back with a more specific question and mocked up data so we can be more specific in the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically: _3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Comment: how do i insert a screen shot?

Comment: You link to an outside source like imugr or dropbox.

Comment: But we would prefer a mock up in the OP, so we do not need to type examples to test.

Comment: Put it in the Original post not in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

[image: Excel Table]

Where `Unique Jobs` and `Unique Dates` are calculated with:

`{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$B$2:$B$13),IF($A$2:$A$13=A2, $B$2:$B$13))>0))}`
and
`{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$C$2:$C$13),IF($A$2:$A$13=A2, $C$2:$C$13))>0))}` respectively. Note the formulas are array formulas which means they need to be entered with <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER</kbd>.

The `IF` statement handles the "are you the employee I care about?" aspect and returns an array of jobs or dates. We take advantage of the fact that when we bin with the same array with `FREQUENCY`, we return a zero for any value it has already seen. The double negation, `--`, coerces the numbers to booleans to ones-and-zeros.

More explanation is available [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-numeric-values-in-a-range).

It's likely possible to do this without the `FREQUENCY` approach or without array formulas, but depending on the size of the dataset, you might want to consider the performance hit.

---

#### UPDATE (per comments):

If you have an additional column, say `column D` = `Job_Type`, you can add criteria to the `IF` condition, like so:

`{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($A$2:$A$13=A2)*($D$2:$D$13="Job Type X"),$B$2:$B$13),IF(($A$2:$A$13=A2)*($D$2:$D$13="Job Type X"),$B$2:$B$13))>0))}`

By utilizing multiplication with an asterisk, `*`, we are implicitly implying an `AND` condition in the logic; note, if we wanted `OR` logic we could use `+`. Also note the additional parentheses. At the end of the day, this says, first check if this is the `Emp` that I care about; next, check if this is the `Job_Type` that I care about; if both of those checkout, return me the column of interest and continue as above.

*NOTE: The method just described will make things yield the same results, by employee, for the specified `Job Type` -- in this example, records with `Job_Type == "Job Type X"`. You could do something like: `{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($A$2:$A$13=A2)*($D$2:$D$13=D2),$B$2:$B$13),IF(($A$2:$A$13 = A2)*($D$2:$D$13=D2),$B$2:$B$13))>0))}` and you would obtain different productivity amounts for each `Emp` and `Job_Type` combination.*

---

Alternatively, you could create a new `Key` column, such as `Emp_Job_Type` which would concatenate the two columns, something like: `=A2&D2`.

Finally, if you are only interested in one particular `Job_type`, you could also consider subsetting or filtering your data beforehand. That is, filter for the records of interest upfront and create a new dataset.

Comment: Depends on how you want to count them. Is the combination of a worker and the job type important? If that's the case, create a new column, that's called `Emp_Job_Type` which `=Emp&Job_Type` (concatenate the two fields together) and treat it as if this was the `Emp` column in my example.

Comment: i want to count the total number of unique days that Emp A does any "All Day jobs", your formula above gets me to the count of every job. Can this bee added without an extra column as an extra criteria for the IF?