# Comparing two columns of data and counting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking through some raw data, I was able to figure out a few things out.  My goal is to write formulas to pull out data and not have to filter, sort, add helper columns and or manipulate the data like I usually have to do.  One of which is to count unique values from a single column.  Here is an example -

[image]

I was able to use `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH('Data Dump'!A2:A10950,'Data Dump'!A2:A10950,0),MATCH('Data Dump'!A2:A10950,'Data Dump'!A2:A10950,0))>0,1))` which worked like a charm!  For this example, I would have counted 8.

I am now trying to compare this column with another one and if it has a specific variable, count it.  Here is an example -

[image]

If I wanted to count the unique successful CHGs, I would have 2 - CHG000483566 and CHG000490961.  Unsuccessful would be 1 - CHG000490708. The good news is this data is always consistent - meaning if the CHG group is successful, all are successful.  Same for unsuccessful.

Can this be done and if so, how?

Comment: Some useful answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944249/count-unique-values-with-a-condition

Comment: Tyvm!  Let me check it out!