# Finding duplicate values in a row using certain criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, duplicates, match, row

This is something I've been struggling with. I made sure to check other threads here and google additional solutions but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

Basically, I want to determine duplicate numbers in a row (total rows are >40,000) but only targeting numbers that are greater than 0.
[image: Screenshot]

So as you can see, the first row has some numbers under columns C1, C2, C3, C4 and C5. Two of them are greater than 0 AND duplicates.

However in the second row there are no duplicate values that are greater than 0.

I can't figure out what formula I should use that would yield the following result:
Expected result
[image]

I would really appreciate your assistance with this.

Comment: One suggestion, you might want to rephrase your spreadsheet to spread out your data across rows, rather than columns.  I'm not sure if `COUNTIFS` works across columns.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the quick response. I've considered that possibility but unfortunately it won't be feasible in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are standard 'count if greater than zero' formulas. For example,

```
=COUNTIF(A2:E2, ">0")
```

There are standard '[count if greater than zero and unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030971/counting-number-of-distinct-people-successfully-contacted-in-a-date-range-excel/50034006#50034006)' formulas. For example,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:E3>0)/(COUNTIFS(A3:E3, A3:E3)+(A3:E3<=0)))
```

If one equals the other then 'unique', otherwise 'duplicate.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:E2, ">0")=SUMPRODUCT((A2:E2>0)/(COUNTIFS(A2:E2, A2:E2)+(A2:E2<=0))), "unique", "duplicate")
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to work well! Thank you so much. I'll read up on the formulas and your link to understand the logic behind them.