# MS Excel count distinct where

Tags: excel

I am using MS Excel 2013, and I am trying to run something like a Count distinct where. Here is my table

```
Name:
jim
james
frank
jillian
jim
john
patrick
jillian
anna
isabelle
```

I am trying to do a count distinct where name starts with a J, which would result in 4. Here is what I have so far.

```
SUMPRODUCT(1/countif([names],[names]))   --- This counts unique names

SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT([names],1)="j"))   --- This counts all names that start with J
```

Im trying to find a way to combine these two together to count unique names that start with J. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count Unique values with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944249/count-unique-values-with-a-condition)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This ended up working.

=SUMPRODUCT(IF(LEFT([names])="j",1/COUNTIF([names],[names])))

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A2:A99)="J")/COUNTIF(A2:A99,A2:A99&""))
```